# simple_form_for not hitting correct controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I have the following path that I want my form to hit:

```
namespace :admin
  resources :jobs do
    member do
      patch 'update_attributes', to: 'jobs#update_attributes', as: 'update_attributes'
```

When I run rake routes this gives:

```
update_attributes_admin_job PATCH /admin/jobs/:id/update_attributes(.:format)          admin/jobs#update_attributes
```

And my simple form:

```
= simple_form_for job, url: update_attributes_admin_job_path(job) do |g|
  .panel.panel-default
    .panel-heading
      Job Summary:
      .pull-right
        = g.submit
    .panel-body
      #job_edit_contacts_component
        .clearfix
          %center
            = g.association :admin, as: :select, collection: Admin.all, label: 'Lead Admin'
          %table.table.table-striped.table-hover
            %thead
             %tr
                %th Select
                %th Attribute
              %tbody
                - status_attributes.each do |attribute|
                  %tr
                    %td 
                      = check_box_tag "attributes[]", attribute, job.send(attribute)
                    %td
                      = attribute.to_s.humanize
```

When I click on submit, the server reads:

```
Started PATCH "/admin/jobs/5846" for ::1 at 2017-11-02 11:06:13 +0000
Processing by Admin::JobsController#update as HTML
```

I've tried simply doing

```
= simple_form_for update_attributes_admin_job_path(job) do |g|
```

However this still submits to the wrong route.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should stay in the default Rails CRUD model. Standard route for update_attributes already present in `resources` call and it's name is `update`. Right now you make some useless overcoding defining your custom `update_attributes` method.

Routes:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :jobs
end
```

View:

```
= simple_form_for [:admin, job] do |g|
```

If you really need this custom update_attributes action (And I am 95% sure you don't), then please comment my post and provide additional details why you do this.

Comment: I was using separate routes as there are multiple forms with different attributes on the same page and it seemed to make sense to handle them like that, would you suggest them all going through the same route?

Comment: If this different forms update the very same object, but just pass different params, then -- yes. #update is pretty generic and you can use it for any kind of updates without any doubts if it's just about different attributes. If you have fully different logic, then I would think about rather separate controller, then separate action.Just keep in mind, that it's not required for a controller to have mapped model.

Answer (score 0):

My form was nested within another form... I didn't realise until trying the second submit button and seeing that it didn't work. The submit button above was therefore linking to the first form, despite the g.submit